# How to check if the image value is null or non-null / (exists or not) in Thymeleaf Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, thymeleaf

I display the image in my index page is as follows

`<img th:src="@{${'/image/'+id}}" />` 
To check if the value of the image is null or not to avoid displaying the img tag without the image, I used if and unless :

`<img th:if="${'/image/'+id} == null" th:src="@{${'/image/'+id}" style="width: 0px;" /> <img th:unless="${'/image/'+id} == null" th:src="@{${'/image/'+id}}" style="width: 50px;" />` 
I did it without success.

The method of the controller class is as follows

```
@GetMapping("/image/{id}")
void showImage(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletResponse response, Optional<ClassImage> classImage)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("Id :: " + id);
        classImage = classImageService.getClassImageById(id);
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif");
        response.getOutputStream().write(classImage.get().getImage());
       response.getOutputStream().close();
}
```

I am a beginner and would like to please ask for your help.

I don't know how to do it

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make sense... are you asking if the variable `id` is null? Then you should just check if `${id == null}`.  (A non-null string + null will never be null, it will always be a string -- thus your current check `${'/image/'+id == null}` will always be true).  If you are asking if you can somehow have thymeleaf know whether or not a request to /image/{id} will be null or not, you can't.  You will have to restructure how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

As I look, you want to implement case sensitive image displaying based on its availability. Please try with this change below.
Your thymeleaf template will go like:

```html
<img th:if="${classImage.isPresent()}" th:src="@{'/image/' + id}" style="width: 50px;" />
<img th:unless="${classImage.isPresent()}" th:src="@{'/image/' + id}" style="width: 0px;" />
```

One step more: your controller will have updated showImage() function.

```java
@GetMapping("/image/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> showImage(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Optional<ClassImage> classImageOptional = classImageService.getClassImageById(id);
    
    if (classImageOptional.isPresent()) {
        ClassImage classImage = classImageOptional.get();
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG); // Update the media type based on your image format
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(classImage.getImage(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Hope my try would help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the work, it helped me see my mistakes. Thanks again